# React with Typescript functional components - how to call child method from parent

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this simplified structure:

```
<Page>
  <Modal>
    <Form />
  </Modal>
</Page>
```

All of these are functional components.
And in `<Modal />` I have a `close` function that looks like this:

```
const close = () => {
  // apply a CSS class - so the modal disappears animatedly ..
  // then use setTimeout() to completely remove the modal after the animation ends ..
}
```

Do you have an idea how the `<Page />` component can call the `<Modal />` close method? And the page has to do it because this is where I'm doing the call to API with the data from the form, and so if all is OK with API request - close the modal.

(The `<Form />` handles only the form validation but then passes the data to `<Page />` where all the business logic happens.)

PS: The project uses Typescript ... so I have to deal with types as well :(

Comment: create a provider, setup on parent, pass handlers to child, call from child

Answer (score 0):

I look into your problem. I think my example should clarify your problem. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
import { ReactNode, useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Page />
    </div>
  )
}

function Page() {
  const [isModalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false)

  const handleFormSubmit = useCallback((formValues: FormValues) => {
    console.log({ formValues })
    setModalOpen(false)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setModalOpen(!isModalOpen)}>Toggle modal</button>

      <Modal isOpen={isModalOpen}>
        <Form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit} />
      </Modal>
    </div>
  )
}

interface ModalProps {
  isOpen: boolean
  children: ReactNode
}
function Modal(props: ModalProps) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)

  const close = () => {
    setIsOpen(false)
  }

  const open = () => {
    setIsOpen(true)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!props.isOpen && isOpen) close()
    if (props.isOpen && !isOpen) open()
  }, [props.isOpen])

  if (!isOpen) return null

  return <div className="modal">{props.children}</div>
}

interface FormProps {
  onSubmit: (formValues: FormValues) => void
}
interface FormValues {
  username: string
  password: string
}
function Form(props: FormProps) {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={e => {
        e.preventDefault()

        props.onSubmit({
          username,
          password
        })
      }}
    >
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="username"
        onChange={e => {
          setUsername(e.target.value)
        }}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="password"
        onChange={e => {
          setPassword(e.target.value)
        }}
      />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  )
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

I assumed you are fresh in FE or React world. Propably you do not need that much-nested structure.

Comment: I understand your idea, but my usecase is different. In the `<Modal />` component I have `close()` function - which makes the modal disappears animatedly and not right away. So - the goal is the `<Page />` component call this function ... Instead of just toggling a property that the `<Modal />` receives. Because with toggling a property the modal will disappear instantly, right?

Comment: I updated the example, try to look again. Actually, it is a bit hacky, but let's see if this will help.

Comment: I think the Modal should have simple API / props to use. Otherwise, it will be hard to re-use it in different components.

Answer (score -1):

There is a special hook in React called useImperativeHandle. You can use it to call child's functions from parent.

You can [find out more](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle) in the [oficcial React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle).

example of usage

**Child Component**

Needs to be wrapped into forwardRef like that:

```
export const ChildComponent = forwardRef((props, ref) => {

useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    async functionName() {
      await someLogic();
    },
  }));
```

**Parent Component**

In parent component you need to pass ref to the child.
Then you can use child's function this way:

```
const childRef = useRef(null)

childRef.current.functionName()
```